# Pesquisar Array() na variavel e banco de dados

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho os seguintes campos em Array():

```
# Tratamento das variaveis para substituição da mensagem
$campos = array(
    0 => '#celular',
    1 => '#ddd',
    2 => '#cpf_cnpj',
    3 => '#nome_razaosocial',
    4 => '#mensagem',
    5 => '#cod_cliente',
    6 => '#cod_contrato',
    7 => '#cod_barras',
    8 => '#valor_divida',
    9 => '#telefone_r_1',
    10 => '#telefone_r_2',
    11 => '#telefone_r_3'
);
```

E tenho também uma variavel:

```
$dados['mensagem'] = "Aqui mensagem #celular #ddd #cod_barras";
```

E tenho o valor destas tags, no banco dedos, na tabela `files_fields`

Preciso verificar na $mensagem se alguma destas tags disponíveis existe, e substituir.

Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
    $sql_dados = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM files_fields LIMIT 5");
    while($row_dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_dados)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_dados['celular']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            //foreach($campos_arr as $valor){ 
                if(in_array($campos, $dados['mensagem'])){ 
                    $mensagem = str_replace($campos, $row_dados[$valor], $dados['mensagem']); 
                } else {
                    $mensagem = $_GET['mensagem'];
                }
            //  echo $mensagem;
        //  } 
        ?>
    </td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Mas retorna o seguinte erro:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
>   D:\Sites\Localhost\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\painel-wallace\php\gerarAmostra.php
>   on line 46

Como eu posso elaborar da maneira correta?

Comment: pra verificar com `in_array` o segundo parametro precisa ser também um `array`

Comment: $dados['mensagem'] = $_GET['mensagem'];

Comment: Editei, a maneira correta

Comment: Parece que chamada de `in_array()` está invertida mesmo assim acho que não vai dar o resultado esperado.

Comment: `$mensagem` tem apenas hashtags?

Comment: Não $mensagem pode ter mensagem e hastag no meio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pensei em algo assim:

```
<?php

$campos = [
   0  => '#celular',
   1  => '#ddd',
   2  => '#cpf_cnpj',
   3  => '#nome_razaosocial',
   4  => '#mensagem',
   5  => '#cod_cliente',
   6  => '#cod_contrato',
   7  => '#cod_barras',
   8  => '#valor_divida',
   9  => '#telefone_r_1',
   10 => '#telefone_r_2',
   11 => '#telefone_r_3'
];

$valor = [
   0  => '(19) 99999-9999',
   1  => '999',
   2  => '999.999.999-99',
   3  => 'Teste de Razão Social',
   4  => 'Obrigado por me testar',
   5  => '99',
   6  => '999',
   7  => '99999999.99999999.99999999.9999999.9.9999999',
   8  => '9.99',
   9  => '(19) 99999-9999',
   10 => '(19) 99999-9999',
   11 => '(19) 99999-9999'
];

$dados['mensagem'] = 'Meu celular é #celular e meu código do cliente é #cod_cliente. Segue o código de barras: #cod_barras';
$mensagem = $dados['mensagem'];

foreach($campos as $key => $item){
   if(strpos($dados['mensagem'], $item)){
      $mensagem = str_replace($item, $valor[$key], $mensagem);
   }
}

echo $mensagem;
```

Veja funcionando nos sites:

[Sandbox PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b844cbdb9af207642d559832a2ee6c340659b66d)

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/I99Yhm)

#### Explicação

`strpos()` - Função que pesquisa a palavra em uma determinada string. Se existir, o retorno é a posição da palavra na string. Quando não encontrar retorna -1.

Fiz o `foreach` para pesquisar no array `$campos` se um ou mais campos existem na variável `$mensagem`. Se existir, substitui pelo valor da mesma posição do array `$valor`, que no seu caso é uma variável que vem da base de dados.

---

No seu caso se o nome dos campos forem iguais aos do array pode ser feito assim:

```
$column = str_replace('#', '', $item);
$mensagem = str_replace($item, $row_dados[$column], $mensagem);
```

Tira **#** do campo com o `str_replace()`.

Ou

```
$mensagem = str_replace($item, $row_dados[$key + 1], $mensagem);
```

`$key + 1` porquê tem o campo ID da tabela provavelmente (não conheço sua tabela)

Comment: $valor é o $row, do banco de dados neste caso

Comment: Sim. Só montei um exemplo pra você ver como que eu faria...

Comment: Mas você pode modificar pra eu ver como ficaria o retorno vindo do banco de dados? dentro do while, neste caso, como eu postei acima?

Comment: será que consegue editar?

Comment: Os campos da tabela estão na sequência dos campos do Array `$campos` ?

Comment: Sim estão sim. ....

Comment: Atualizei meu poste... http://www.ecrau.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/poste.jpg